# How to set the token amount into the script

Tags: rust, spl-associated-token-account, spl

How can I incorporate tokens into the script? For instance, I need to send tokens like USDT, and the token value might be something like 12.067. When I send this value, it sometimes doesn't transfer the correct amount. How can I handle these decimal values in the script?

```
        Math.floor(amounts ** 1e6)
```

I set this but still, it sends 10342.489 like this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you should check how many decimals is used for the said token.

Once you have the correct amount of decimals, i never had any problem using something like 12067000000 for example if  9 decimals

Comment: Thanks for help